# Multiple JSON files, parse, and load into tables

Tags: json, parsing

I'm a real beginner when it comes time for this, so I apologize in advance.

The long and short of what I am looking for is a fairly simple concept - I want to pull JSON data off a server, parse it, and load it into excel, access, or some other type of tables.  Basically, I want to be able to store the data so I can filter, sort, and query it.

To make matters a little more complicated, the server will only return truncated results with each JSON, so it will be necessary to make multiple requests to the server.

Are there tools out there or code available which will help me do what I am looking for?  I am completely lost, and I have no idea where to start.

(please be gentle)

Comment: Where abouts are you going to be coding the Parser? In excel?

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad seeing this question b/c I'm doing very similar things! And based on what I'd gone through, it has lot to do with how those tables are designed or even linked together at first, and then the mapping between these tables and different JSON objects at different depth or position in the original JSON file. After the mapping rules are made clear, the code can be done by merely hard-coding the mapping(I mean like: if you got JSON object after a certain parent of it, then you save the data into certain table(s)) if you're using some high level JSON paring library.

Answer (score 0):

OK as i have to dash home from the office now:

Assuming that you are going to use Excel to Parse the data you are going to need:

1.Some Json Parser [JSON Parser for VBA](http://www.exceltoolset.com/free-excel-tool-json-parser-for-vba/)
2.Some code to download the JSON
3.A loop of VBA code that loops through each file and parses it into a sheet.

Is this ok for a starter? If you are struggling let me know and I will try and knock something up a little better over the weekend.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need.  As I mentioned, I'm a real novice when it comes time for this stuff, so any further direction is greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: Any other advice you might be able to give?

Comment: Sorry yes - I have just got into the office, I need to do a few bits and bobs for HP first then I will see what I can put together for you on my lunch break :-)